# Drawing graphs in Latex using documentclass "memoir"

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am using "memoir" in Latex to draw graphs. I am getting errors. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in the following?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,oldfontcommands,12pt]{memoir}

%%% INCLUDE THE PACKAGES

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{a4wide}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{amssymb, hyperref}

\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{node distance=2cm, auto}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\usepackage{calc,graphicx,soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, every loop/.style={}]

\vertex[fill] (1) at (.2, 0) [label=below:1]  {};

\vertex [fill](2) at (0,.2) [label=left:2] {};

\vertex[fill] (3) at (.2,.4) [label=above:3] {};

\vertex[fill] (4) at (.4,.4) [label=above:4] {}; 

\vertex[fill] (5) at (.4, 0) [label=below:5] {}; 

\vertex [fill](6) at (.6,.2) [label=right:6] {};

\vertex[fill] (7) at (1.2, 0) [label=below:1]  {};

\vertex [fill](8) at (1,.2) [label=left:2] {};

\vertex[fill] (9) at (1.2,.4) [label=above:3] {};

\vertex[fill] (10) at (1.4,.4) [label=above:4] {};

\vertex[fill] (11) at (1.6, .2) [label=right:6] {}; 

\vertex [fill](12) at (1.4,0) [label=below:5] {};

\vertex[fill] (13) at (2.2, 0) [label=below:1] {}; 

\vertex [fill](14) at (2,.2)  [label=left:2]  {};

\vertex[fill] (15) at (2.2,.4)  [label=above:3]{};

\vertex[fill] (16) at (2.4,.4) [label=above:4] {};

\vertex[fill] (17) at (2.6,.2) [label=right: 6]  {};

\vertex [fill](18) at (2.4,0) [label=below:5] {};   

\path

    (1) edge (2)
    (1) edge (3)
    (2) edge (3)
    (4) edge (5)
    (4) edge (6)
    (5) edge (6)
    (7) edge (8)
    (8) edge (9)
    (9) edge (10)
    (7) edge (12)
    (10) edge (11)
    (11) edge (12)
    (13) edge (14)
    (14) edge (15)
    (15) edge (18)
    (13) edge (16)
    (16) edge (17)
    (17) edge (18)
 ;  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not really related to memoir at all

Answer (score 1):

`\vertex` is undefined. I think you are looking for `\coordinate`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,oldfontcommands,12pt]{memoir}

%%% INCLUDE THE PACKAGES

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{a4wide}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{amssymb, hyperref}

\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{node distance=2cm, auto}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\usepackage{calc,graphicx,soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, every loop/.style={}]

\coordinate[fill] (1) at (.2, 0) [label=below:1]  {};

\coordinate [fill](2) at (0,.2) [label=left:2] {};

\coordinate[fill] (3) at (.2,.4) [label=above:3] {};

\coordinate[fill] (4) at (.4,.4) [label=above:4] {}; 

\coordinate[fill] (5) at (.4, 0) [label=below:5] {}; 

\coordinate [fill](6) at (.6,.2) [label=right:6] {};

\coordinate[fill] (7) at (1.2, 0) [label=below:1]  {};

\coordinate [fill](8) at (1,.2) [label=left:2] {};

\coordinate[fill] (9) at (1.2,.4) [label=above:3] {};

\coordinate[fill] (10) at (1.4,.4) [label=above:4] {};

\coordinate[fill] (11) at (1.6, .2) [label=right:6] {}; 

\coordinate [fill](12) at (1.4,0) [label=below:5] {};

\coordinate[fill] (13) at (2.2, 0) [label=below:1] {}; 

\coordinate [fill](14) at (2,.2)  [label=left:2]  {};

\coordinate[fill] (15) at (2.2,.4)  [label=above:3]{};

\coordinate[fill] (16) at (2.4,.4) [label=above:4] {};

\coordinate[fill] (17) at (2.6,.2) [label=right: 6]  {};

\coordinate [fill](18) at (2.4,0) [label=below:5] {};   

\path

    (1) edge (2)
    (1) edge (3)
    (2) edge (3)
    (4) edge (5)
    (4) edge (6)
    (5) edge (6)
    (7) edge (8)
    (8) edge (9)
    (9) edge (10)
    (7) edge (12)
    (10) edge (11)
    (11) edge (12)
    (13) edge (14)
    (14) edge (15)
    (15) edge (18)
    (13) edge (16)
    (16) edge (17)
    (17) edge (18)
 ;  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to add \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt]
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}

Comment: @a.nayek Yes, it works. However, consider using `\tikzset`, as `\tikzstyle` is not commonly used anymore.

Comment: @a.nayek Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I agree. This was a comment mainly addressed to the OP.

Comment: @a.nayek I wouldn't use `\vertex` because it is already used in `tikz-feynman`.